# C#,LINQ to SQL, Insert data in Joined Tables

Tags: linq-to-sql

this z my first question here and answer will be highly appreciated,

I have two table:-

```
Table1:     EMPLOYEE{eid int(PK,identity), ename varchar}
Table 2:    Sales {sid int(PK,identity), eid int(FK), totalsales money}
```

I want to insert data using `LINQ` to `sql`.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you have proper foreign keys you can save all at once like this (by heart, so please check proper spelling but you should get the works)

```
Using (db = new yourdatacontext())
{
  Employee em = new Employee;
  em.name = "somename";

  db.Employees.InsertOnSubmit(e);

  Sales s = new Sales();
  s.totalsales = 10000;
  em.Sales.Add(s)

db.Submitchanges();

}
```

The important part to keep from this is that you do not need to mess with PK or Foreign Keys or Identities. Linq-to-sql will  take care of all that for you. Also transaction is kept in submitchanges. That is the beauty of Linq-to-sql

Answer (score -2):

It will most likely be something like:

```
Employee employee = new Employee();

//populate Employee object

db.Employees.Add(employee);
```

**EDIT:** Then after adding the employee, populate the Sales object and add it to the db as well:

```
Sales sales = new Sales();

sales.eid = employee.id;

db.Sales.Add(sales);
```

I.e. save to the Employee table first to get the generated Id.

For more information, [ScottGu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/11/linq-to-sql-part-4-updating-our-database.aspx) explains this quite well.

Comment: thx. but I want to insert data in both tables, when identity is auto increasing, How I can add values in Table 2.

Comment: See my edited answer. I very much recommend you read through ScottGu's blog.

Comment: This is not the right way to do things.  Pleun below is doing it right with the linked objects.  If you are adding parent and child at the same time, then saving between the two is wasteful.  Almost always if you find yourself assigning primary keys to foreign keys you are doing it wrong, let the framework do the connecting for you.